# How can we implemement maps with values of different data types in C++ like in PHP?

Tags: php, c++, matrix, data-structures

In PHP, we can create arrays like:

```
$somearray[0]['key1']= $someOtherArray;
$somearray[0]['key2']= 6;
$somearray[0]['key3']= 12.73647;
```

This is basically a matrix having values of dissimilar data types (`$someOtherArray` is another php array). I want to implement this in C++ somehow. Should I use maps or should I use two different data structures in combination or something like that? What's the best solution?

Comment: Sounds like you want `std::variant` or `std::any` or the boost equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

How about polymorphism (will only work for user defined types (so no primitives))

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class BaseClass {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    BaseClass(int x) : x(x) {}

    virtual int GetValue() { return x; }
};

class Child1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    Child1(int x) : BaseClass(x) {}
    int GetValue() override { return x * 2; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> map;

    map[0] = std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>(new BaseClass(1));
    map[1] = std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>(new Child1(1));

    std::cout << map[0]->GetValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << map[1]->GetValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the alternative to std::variant... For primitives, you could write a wrapper template class.